# Is using fcntl F_SETLKW on STDOUT_FILENO legal?

Tags: c, linux, synchronization, posix

I have multiple processes spawned via fork from main program, which means they output to same stdout (which I want). However I need to somehow prevent the output from being interleaved. I already use fcntl locks to synchronize access to log file so I wanted to use it also for stdout.

However [this](https://gavv.github.io/articles/file-locks/) blog post claims that fcntl locks are `associated with an [i-node, pid] pair`. Do stdout have an inode? I've decided to just try it

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

void do_log(const char *msg) {
    printf("%5ld: %s\n", getpid(), msg);
}

void try_lock(void) {
    do_log("Trying to lock stdout...");

    struct flock fl = {
        .l_type = F_WRLCK,
        .l_whence = SEEK_SET,
        .l_start = 0,
        .l_len = 0,
    };
    if (fcntl(STDOUT_FILENO, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl - lock");
        exit(1);
    }

    do_log("Stdout locked");
    sleep(2);
    do_log("Trying to unlock stdout...");

    fl.l_type = F_UNLCK;
    if (fcntl(STDOUT_FILENO, F_SETLKW, &fl) == -1) {
        perror("fcntl - unlock");
        exit(1);
    }

    do_log("Stdout unlocked");
}

int main(void) {
    if (fork()) {
        try_lock();
    } else {
        try_lock();
    }
    wait(NULL);
    return 0;
}
```

which seems to work

```
17156: Trying to lock stdout...
17155: Trying to lock stdout...
17155: Stdout locked
17155: Trying to unlock stdout...
17155: Stdout unlocked
17156: Stdout locked
17156: Trying to unlock stdout...
17156: Stdout unlocked
```

but in manpage for fcntl I've noticed `If fildes refers to a typed memory object, the result of the fcntl() function is unspecified.` and I have no idea what that means.

So I guess I have two questions:

1. Is using fcntl lock on stdout like this guaranteed to work?
2. If answer to 1. is yes, is the blog post wrong about `[i-node, pid]` or does stdout actually have an i-node?

Comment: It is unlikely that standard input would be a 'typed memory object'.  That requires special work to set it up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An inode number (along with device number) is purely a unique identifier for a file. It has nothing to do, in modern usage of the term, with on-disk filesystem structures. All files (and file descriptors refer to instances of open files) have an inode number, and doing `fcntl` at least "makes sense" on them. However, per POSIX:

> Record locking shall be supported for regular files, and may be supported for other files.

It's possible that there are some file types on which Linux doesn not support locks; I'm not sure.

Note also that locking is purely *advisory* - it has no effect if the processes doing the writing don't attempt to take the lock before performing their access.

It may make more sense, especially if you're using `fork` without `exec`, to do locking via shared memory. Before forking, `mmap` a `MAP_ANON|MAP_SHARED` region and setup a process-shared mutex in it. You can make this a robust mutex if any process might be able to die unexpectedly. This is guaranteed to work, and should be faster too since it's purely a userspace operation except on lock contention.